# SSO with SAML in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to SAML and I need some clarification.

I have one asp.net mvc application. I want my application to authenticated by other application user which are authentic/exist  in my application

So , How to implement this ???
If other application user is able to access (authorized) my application.
I need to create the Idp for this purpose.

Any step by step code sample will be helpful. Could you please please shed some light in how to use SAML.

Comment: http://www.componentpro.com/doc/saml/AtAGlance.htm

Comment: https://coding.abel.nu/2014/08/kentor-authservices-saml2-owin-middleware-released/ This stuff is opensourced under GPL.